# Running Seleniuem web driver 2.53.0 with Firefox 47.0

Tags: selenium, firefox

I have just started running test scripts using selenium web driver. I coded the following code as a start.

```
    package myPackage;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class myTest {
       public static void main(String[] args){

            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }
```

When I run it as Java application, It always shows the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main"    org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

Just the browser opens, but the facebook page doesn't get opened.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: How do you know its an eclipse issue? have you tried running the jar from terminal?

Comment: The issue is not with eclipse, it is a issue arising with compatibility of Firefox and Selenium.I tried it with using Netbeans IDE, Same problem occurs.

Comment: Then please remove eclipse tag and eclipse title.

Comment: I have instaled Firefox 47.0 and Selenium Webdriver 2.53.0.